# Google Analytics in real time for personalization

Tags: google-analytics, real-time, google-analytics-api, google-analytics-firebase

Is there a way in Google Analytics to get a visitors information in real time in order to personalize content?

For example, visitor A comes from Google using the "widgets" keyword and using a Chrome browser so I want to show him content related to Chrome based widgets.

Comment: Your example is probably the worst possible example as (organic) keywords won't even be available if users come from an ssl secured search page (i.e. 90% of visits).

Comment: Yes, my point was trying to give a naively simple example.  But I didn't specify whether the medium was organic or cpc either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google Analytics provides a Real Time Reporting API as a developer preview in **limited beta**.

[Real Time Reporting API Private Beta](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/1qfRFysCikpgCMGqgF3yXdUyQW4xAlLyjKuOoOEFN2Uw/viewform) access request form.

With all the limitations that this means it may be worth giving a try. 
You can find *Java*, *PHP*, and *Python* code examples on the documentation page: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/realtime/v3/reference/data/realtime/get

In **PHP** this is the anatomy of the call to the API:

```
$optParams = array(
    'dimensions' => 'rt:medium');

try {
  $results = $analytics->data_realtime->get(
      'ga:56789',
      'rt:keyword',
      $optParams);
```

Comment: Thanks... do you know of any other analytics services that offer this type of real time functionality that are beyond a beta version?

Comment: Don't worry that its in beta its stable. Just apply for access takes about 24 hours.

Comment: Dirk, I agree with @DaImTo.

Answer (score 0):

Probably not.  Even if you request from the the Real-time API keyword you will find that. The Keyword returned is the Keyword from your own campaign tracking.  So this would only work on links that you sent back to yourself  Which really isn't what you want to do.  Its a nice idea really

Documentation: [rt:keyword](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/realtime/dimsmets/trafficsources#rt:keyword)

> When using manual campaign tracking, the value of the utm_term
>   campaign tracking parameter. When using AdWords autotagging or if a
>   user used organic search to reach your property, the keywords used by
>   users to reach your property. Otherwise the value is (not set).

What you are looking for is the keyword that would be used against a search engine. That keyword isn't returned via the Real-time api.

Comment: @DalmTo Where it says: __if a user used organic search to reach your property, the keywords used by users to reach your property.__ That's actually the keyword used to reach the page via Organic Search. Otherwise it will be a campaign keyword or "not set".

Comment: @carlodurso you might be right.  This will require more testing.

Comment: Site search appears to return keyword "(not provided)" which is weird since it is showing active page /?s=ssis for  http://www.daimto.com/?s=ssis

Comment: Thanks... I'm less interested in keyword specifically than any of the data in general.

Comment: you might also want to consider the quota limit.  depending upon how many users you have on your site you are quickly going to blow out the quota limit.